# How to test the multiple test cases in a single test case using selenium webdriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

I am in confusion to write the test cases for one of my requirement.I have a signup process it will have 8 steps to complete a signup.How to write a test script for all steps by validating the each and every validation for single field.
I am using the java along with selenium webdriver
how the framework should like ?

All validations should take in a single test case ?

I am happy and welcome with your ideas/approch

Comment: You should probably mention what technology you are using together with Selenium to write your tests, i.e. Python, Ruby, Java. In most cases though, there should be a clear difference between test steps and test cases. Your 8 steps of the signup process should become test steps, forming a single test case.

Answer (score 1):

1. Separate your actions on a webpage from test cases. Follow Page object pattern/framework.
2. You can use junit or testNg unit testing framework to write your test cases. I would advise you to use testNg as gives you lot of flexibility.
3. Now you like to validate all 8 steps that you want to execute, now the question is what if first step fails, what do you want to do next?
   a) Do you want to fail a test case and stop the execution there? Or, 
   b)You want to execute all the steps without worrying its validation status and report status at the end?

For (a) its very straightforward, use `Assert.assertEquals(actual, expect)` method.
If you want to follow (b) then you would like to use soft Assertion which will allow you to execute all the steps and it report cumulative status in the end.

For soft Assertions using junit, find out details [here](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/SoftAssertions.html).
For test, find it [here](http://javadox.com/org.testng/testng/6.8/org/testng/asserts/SoftAssert.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of test framework. If you use Java I recommend to use TestNG. Then you can use assertion (e.g. `Assert.assertTrue(yourCondition, message)` for all fields, it depends on test case and your goal. Note that if any assertion is failed then test execution is finished. 
If you want to prepare test cases with different login data you can use DataProvider from TestNG.

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing you should do is create a matrix of your steps which will give you exact idea how many test scenarios you have to test.

Based on the matrix create a CSV (or any other data provider) according to matrix and add the data. Each row of CSV will be 1 test scenario and each row will have additional column which is expected output for e.g: if user name is invalid then a expected error message should be given for test scenario.

Now write a function which will read the data from CSV   row by row and assert the expected output with actual output.

Hope it helps you.